# The permission tab isn't showing in snap store

Tags: snap, snap-store

I've followed [this](https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces) guide by Ubuntu on how to manage snap permissions, but I've noticed that my Ubuntu store doesn't have the permission section
[image]

Any idea on why is this happening?
I'm currently on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and my system is fully updated both apt and snap and thanks

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, i added the link

Comment: I don't use the application in question, but is it possible that this particular snap just doesn't need or request any additional permissions?

Comment: It seems that other apps I had installed didn't have the permissions e.g. VS Code, Pycharm, I checked by installing another application, and it did show the permissions for it, thanks